# str_replace and SQL Server queries with PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, escaping

I used to do ASP (vbscript) Programming, and have recently tried to start using PHP. I used to have a function in ASP that allowed to to replace ' with ''.

This was used for queries with a SQL Server database. I was just wondering if it is as easy to use  something like this for PHP. I am aware of addslashes and stripslashes but it doesn't really serve the exact purpose I want.

Say I had a simple query like:

```
$dbTABLE = "Table_Name";
$query_sql = sprintf("UPDATE %s SET DataText = ('%s') WHERE PageID = '%d'",
$dbTABLE,
$PageHTML,
$PageID);
```

Is there a way to wrap it in something like str_replace to tell it that all ' should be replaced with ''?

I know I could search for it with a SQL Server query, but it needs to be before the data from a textarea is put into the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function:

```
str_replace("'", "''", "Neil O'Brien")
```

The example code you posted would look like:

```
$dbTABLE = "Table_Name";
$query_sql = sprintf("UPDATE [%s] SET DataText = '%s' WHERE PageID = %d",
$dbTABLE,
str_replace("'", "''", $PageHTML),
$PageID);
```

I suggest using some kind of library instead of building queries yourself.